# Paraview Visualization Remote connection errors

Tags: segmentation-fault, paraview, remote-connection

everyone! when I try the paraview 5.9.1 remote connection between cluster(server) and win10(client GUI). it shows client connected, but one second later it gives the error: Segmentation fault(core dumped). I donot know what is wrong with it? If anyone could give me suggestions, I appreciate. The steps in detail are as following:

Step 1:

```
$ ssh XX@hawk.hww.hlrs.de
```

(then I could get the login node:hawk-login04)

step2:

from local shell:

```
$ ssh -L 11111:hawk-login04:22222 XX@hawk.hww.hlrs.de
```

(here I could connect successfully)

step 3:

from cluster:

```
hawk-login04$ module load paraview/server/(version)
hawk-login04$ pvserver --server-port=22222
Waiting for client...
Connection URL: cs://hawk-login04:22222
Accepting connection(s): hawk-login04:22222
```

step4:

from local paraview client:

```
->File->connection->add Server-> Server Type:Client/Server → Host:localhost → Port:11111 save.
```

At the time I click connect, from the cluster it shows:

```
Waiting for client...
Connection URL: cs://hawk-login04:22222
Accepting connection(s): hawk-login04:22222
Client connected.
Loguru caught a signal: SIGSEGV
Stack trace:
10            0x40173e pvserver() [0x40173e]
9       0x7fd159edb7b3 __libc_start_main + 243
8             0x401659 pvserver() [0x401659]
7       0x7fd157a3dc21 vtkTCPNetworkAccessManager::ProcessEventsInternal(unsigned long, bool) + 609
6       0x7fd156976d99 vtkMultiProcessController::ProcessRMIs(int, int) + 729
5       0x7fd156976580 vtkMultiProcessController::ProcessRMI(int, void*, int, int) + 272
4       0x7fd15823972d vtkPVSessionServer::OnClientServerMessageRMI(void*, int) + 1101
3       0x7fd1582392aa vtkPVSessionServer::GatherInformationInternal(unsigned int, char const*, unsigned int, vtkMultiProcessStream&) + 714
2       0x7fd1579ebf8f vtkPVDataInformation::CopyParametersFromStream(vtkMultiProcessStream&) + 111
1       0x7fd15697c130 vtkMultiProcessStream::operator>>(std::string&) + 224
0       0x7fd159eef880 /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x37880) [0x7fd159eef880]
(  20.065s) [pvserver        ]                       :0     FATL| Signal: SIGSEGV
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please prefer plain text for error message over images : it is easier to parse, to copy/paste elements and future people with the same issue will be able to find this thread. (more [arguments](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: can you specify the ParaView version ? Please also check the pvserver version

Comment: For future ref, it is a crosspost from ParaView [forum](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/paraview-remote-connection-failed/7594)

Comment: I use the paraview 5.9.1. Both paraviews are matched with version 5.9.1